# How to handle sitemaps for pages with path parameters?

Tags: search-engine, sitemap

I noticed that some website are capable of providing a URL like:

> https://www.example.com/cars/new%20york

and get Google to display something like

> **320 cars found in NewYork**
>   Get cars here at EXAMPLE.COM
>   https://www.example.com/cars/new%20york

in the search results (note that there's also the *number* of cars displayed).

I'd like to optimize my website in the same way thus I am currently working on a sitemap. However, I don't see how search engines would be able to "guess" all the possible parameters to this.

I was thinking that I could e.g. *generate* a sitemap with **all** possible parameters (e.g. all cities):

```
https://www.example.com/cars/new%20york
https://www.example.com/cars/vienna
https://www.example.com/cars/rome
```

and put them in my sitemaps.xml

That's a semi-optimal solution imho because in theory on can have `example.com/cars/anything%20you%20want`.

So - is there another way to achieve what this or will it be necessary to create this (rather huge) list of urls and host it?

Comment: Looking at some sitemaps of websites using this shady practice, they seem to generate the huge list ([example](https://www.autotrader.com/sitemap_srp_index_all.xml))…

Comment: @helb Uargh .. yeah I actually came to the same conclusion. It feels dirty to do that but I guess there's just not really another way. After all, how would a search engine know that it is suppsed to put a city there :/